# find option as command line argument

Tags: command-line, find, options

I have got a problem with my script. I am trying to write a script, where option for command find is the first command line argument.

In my script I've got something like

```
find_option=$1

find $find_option
```

The problem is that for example for find option `*.txt` the output is just the first text file in my directory, but I would like to find all such files.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us exactly how you invoke your script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you give your script the pattern like so,

```
./myscript '*.txt'
```

(the quotes are necessary to avoid expanding the pattern to names in the current directory), then you may write your script like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

name_pattern=$1

find . -name "$name_pattern"
```

This takes the first command line argument and uses it in a call to `find`, filtering the names found in the current directory and below by the given pattern.

Note that here too you need to quote the variable expansion of `$name_pattern` in the call to `find` for the same reason that you needed to quote it on the command line when calling your script, i.e. to avoid expanding the pattern to names in the current directory.

Comment: Thank  you. And what if I have got more options for find on command line such as . -type f  -name "*.txt"?

Comment: @user402980 If you do, it seems as if your script is not of much benefit over calling `find` directly. If you have an update or clarification to your question, please consider modifying your question.